# Solving a system of simultaneous linear differential equations with constant coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

---

The equation I have is this:

$$Dx + y = \sin t$$
$$Dy + x = e^{3t}    \rightarrow \times D$$

I solved it this way:

$$Dx + y = \sin t  \rightarrow (1)$$
$$Dx + D^2y= D(e^{3t})\rightarrow (2)$$

(1)-(2)

$$ y- D^2y= \sin t- 3e^{3t}$$
$$ (D^2-1)y= 3e^{3t}-\sin t$$

I would be solving the P.I for $y$ and not $x$ (as in my textbook) and this leads to a variation in the answers.

$$C.F= Ae^t+Be^{-t}$$

$$P.I = \frac {1}{D^2-1}3e^{3t}- \frac{1}{D^2-1}\sin t$$

Solving,

$$P.I = \frac {3}{8}e^{3t}+ \frac{1}{2}\sin t$$

$$y = Ae^t+Be^{-t} +\frac{3}{8} +\frac{1}{2}\sin t$$

Whereas the answer for $y$ as per my book is,

$$y= \sin t- Ae^t+Be^{-t} +\frac{3}{8} -\frac{1}{2}\sin t$$

So is my value right? Or do I have to solve it in a particular way? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tip: Use `\sin` and `\cos` to format trig functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you got the same answer as your book. In the book's answer, you can simplify $\sin t - \frac{1}{2}\sin t = + \frac{1}{2}\sin t$; and since $A$ is an arbitrary constant, you can replace it with $-A$, which gives your answer.

Comment: Ohhh whoa I just realised I could simplify $$sin\,t- \frac{1}{2} sin\,t$$. Thank you!